# finding an address in a sharded ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

In the future, Ethereum shall be a network of blockchains, all joined by a common root. This will allow for performance improvements in addition to the use of the proof of stake consensus.

Having a lot of shards is nice, but it makes finding the destination address for transactions somewhat tricky. Will there be a chain prefix in each address or a special address repository?

In short: how will the address system work in a sharded ethereum?

Comment: http://vitalik.ca/files/mauve_paper3.html